# Event listener triggers on extension icon click, not popup button

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, browser-extension

I'm developing a browser extension where the user can click on one of many buttons in the popup. I have my code stored in popup.js. The following code is supposed to execute only when you click the button with id="green". Instead, it executes whenever you click the extension's icon for the first time.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
  

<html>
    <head>
      <style>
        button {
          height: 20px;
          width: 100px;
          outline: none;
        }
      </style>
      
    </head>
    <body>
      <button id="oolong">Oolong</button>
      <button id="green">Green</button>
      <button id="purerh">PurErh</button>
      <button id="Black">Black</button>
      <span id="audio"></span>
      <script src="popup.js"></script>
    </body>
  </html>
```

```
document.getElementById("green").addEventListener("click", alert("Test"))
```

What do I need to do to make it only execute on the click of the button with id='green'?

Comment: That event listener is not supposed to execute anything, `alert` returns `undefined`, and that is what `#green` [is going to listen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/addEventListener). Please add more context to the code. There is an outer event listener, which is trying to attach a new listener, if this code is run on a click.

Comment: Done, see above.

Comment: Please show more code around the JS line you've posted.

Comment: There is no more.

Comment: You've misunderstood how `addEventListener` works. In short, the handler argument should be a function _reference_. When you attach an event listener, element's `addEventListener` method is called. That native function adds the event in the intrinsic event queue, and the function passed as an argument is called from that queue when an event which is listened fires. This mechanism is often called "_callback_". In your code, `alert` is called immediately, and its return value (`undefined`) is passed to `addEventListener`, and attaching the event fails. David's answer is correct, just follow it.

Answer (score 1):

```
document.getElementById("green").addEventListener("click", function(){alert("Test")})
```

You have pass to `addEventListener` a function to execute. What you are doing is passing the return of a execution

Comment: This is a call: alert("Test") Everywhere you put it as callback you are using its return value. To use alert as callback you shouldn't call it (set it without ("Test")) so you would be calling alert with an object which it's not what you are looking for